# Insert element value and data from database to textarea with jquery

Tags: jquery, formatting, textarea

I was wondering how can i insert a value of a textbox and a value that i retrieved from a database to a textarea, upon clicking a button?

I have a table and the 1st row are all textboxes that you can input a number. The 2nd row is the data that i retrieved from the database. The last row is an add button.

How do i append the value on the textbox and data to a textarea on click of the button?

**Edit:**

just to make it clear.

I have multiple columns on each row.
Each column has a textbox.

I want to add the value of the textbox and the value of the data that i retrieved from the database to the textarea.

**Answered**

thank you to sir [artm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309109/artm) for the answer

to those who want to know here it is: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsddffx1/26/)

```
$('.buttonAdd').click(function(){
  var td = $(this).parent();
  var tr = td.parent();
  var rowIndex = tr.parent().children().index(tr);

  var textBoxValue = $("#example tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(0) input").val();
  var dbValue = $("#example tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(1) span").text();
alert(textBoxValue + " " + dbValue);  

 var text = textBoxValue + dbValue
$('textarea').val( $('textarea').val() + " " + text +"\n" );
```

});

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you have a textboxe for each column or a single textbox? Do you want to get the text from the textbox from all columns in the 2nd row or the row below the textbox?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear, yes i have a textbox on each column and i just want the text and data from the current column to be added to the textarea.

Comment: And you have a button per column on the last row, correct? All in single a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this; if you put a class to the buttons on the last row, then you can get the column index from the event. Then table first row -> col_index is textbox value, 2nd row -> col_index is value from db.

```
$('.buttonAdd').click(function(){
  //this.parent = 'td'
  var td = $(this).parent();
  var colIndex = td.parent().children().index(td);
  var textBoxValue = $("#tableID tr:eq(0) td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").val();
  var dbValue = $("#tableID tr:eq(1) td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").val();
});
```

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/rsddffx1/14/

```
$('.buttonAdd').click(function(){
     var td = $(this).parent();
     var tr = td.parent();
     var rowIndex = tr.parent().children().index(tr);

     var textBoxValue = $("#example tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(0) input").val();
     var dbValue = $("#example tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(1) span").text();
     alert(textBoxValue + " " + dbValue);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but i'm a bit confused on how to do this

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with your layout and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I don't really know how to use jsfiddle, but i tried to combine your code with Leo's answer below or above.

Comment: For a jsfiddle example see http://jsfiddle.net/rsddffx1/4/ Ignore the JS section, change the html section to show us what kind of table/dom you have. My understanding was last row had the button, but now it looks like the last column has the button.

Comment: @AccullusHartlezZeltania When you change the fiddle, click update or save and post the link here.

Comment: oh thank you! sir. this is what i've been looking for and i just tweeked it a bit to fit what i needed. here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/rsddffx1/26/

Answer (score 0):

Try Folowing code:

Jquery Code:

```
var fromtextbox= $('#textbox').val();  //from text box
var fromdb="hello"; //"<?php echo $fromdb;?>"; from database 
var finaltext=fromtextbox + fromdb;

$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('#txtarea').val(finaltext);
  });

$("#btn1").click(function(){
   var textval= $('#txtarea').val();
    alert(textval);
  });
```

HTML CODE:

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="this is text box"/>   

<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<button id="btn">click on me</button>
<button id="btn1">get data from   me</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrv46rda/1/

Comment: Who said anything about `PHP`..?

Comment: read this"
I was wondering how can i insert a value of a textbox and a value that i retrieved from a database to a textarea, upon clicking a button?"

Comment: I don't see any `PHP` in there..?

Comment: @T J .He is talikng about value from db and textbox.User also added in edit section "I want to add the value of the textbox and the value of the data that i retrieved from the database to the textarea."i just written  sample code that how he can do this !!

Comment: So what does it has to do with `PHP`?  you think the only way to retrieve value from a db is using `PHP`..?!

Answer (score 0):

This should do, make sure you specify the correct selectors. Assuming you're retrieving values from only one element/column...

```
var v1 = $('{your_input_selector}').val();
var v2 = $('{your_table_cell_selector}').html();

$('{your_textarea_selector}').val(v1 + v2);
```

however, if you are retrieving values from more than one element (multiple columns in the table), here's a code snippet

```js
$(function() {

  var v1 = '';
  var v2 = '';

  $('input[type=button]').click(function() {

    $('td input[type=text]').each(function() {
      v1 = v1 + $(this).val();
    });

    $('tr:eq(1) td:eq').each(function() {
      v2 = v2 + $(this).html();
    });

    $('textarea').val(v1 + v2);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
table td {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="Value 1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="Value 2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="Value 3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="button" value="Add Data" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but this isn't what i was looking for although it's close.

Comment: it should look something like...  1st column.. value 1 || data 1 || add data .. 2nd column value 2 || data 2 || add data.. and so on. And when i click on the add button. it should only add the data on the current row

Comment: @AccullusHartlezZeltania I have provided all the info you need. What else do you want? A whole solution???? How about reading a jQuery tutorial?

Comment: sorry but i was just confused about how the script takes the values in the current column

Comment: @AccullusHartlezZeltania using jquery and css selectors...the latter has been around for absolute ages